# Is/Am/Are and To be

Tags: grammar

Can some one explain me when we use a form of to be verb (is/am/are) and when we use "to be" or "be" instead of "is/am/are"?

For example:

Why bellow sentence doesn't use is/am/are but "to be"?

> I need this to be done within a hour

Comment: *To be done* is a passive construction. Another example is 'I need this ice cream *to be eaten* within an hour.'

Comment: *to be done* means that someone will do the action, but you don't know who because since it's a passive construction, it's focused on the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "to be" is used in your sentence because "need" is followed by a "to infinitive". For example, *You need to tell her you love her.*

Secondly, in this case, just like Alan Carmack comments, after "need" comes a passive construction (verb "be" in any  tense + the past participle of the main verb), so need + to infinitive = need to be + past participle.

Thus, in passive voice you may have any tense :
S.Present - am/is/are + P.P. For example, *I am criticized by my parents.*
S.Past - was/were + P.P. For example *They were sent to jail.*

It is the verb "be" the one you conjugate to produce the tense. Besides this usage, "be", may be the main verb + an adjective or a noun. For example, *You are hardworking.* or *She was a film star*.

Finally, "be" may be an auxiliary + an -ing verb to produce continuous (progressive) tenses. For example, *They are typing their homework now* or *His mom was cooking when he arrived.*

**Usages of "be" without to:**
A) AFTER MODAL AUXILIARIES
(can/could/may/might/shall/should/will/would/must/have to/needn't/ought to) + BE
For example, *He must be sick.* or *We needn't be in that class.*

B) AFTER ADJECTIVES EXPRESSING NECESSITY, URGENCY OR ADVICE
(essential/ crucial/obligatory/necessary etc.) in the following formal constructions:
For example, *It is necessary that he be more careful.*

C) AFTER VERBS EXPRESSING ADVICE, URGENCY OR NECESSITY (recommend/insist/suggest/demand, etc.)
For example, *They recommend(ed  (that)) we be sensible of the situation.*

Comment: Thank you very much, very clearly and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

The primary auxiliaries "is, am and are" are used in the simple present tense to show the connection between the subject and a noun or adjective that comes after the verb.

[Here](http://www.englishpractice.com/learning/beginner-level-2/)'s a little explanation to it along with some examples.

Whereas, "to be done" is a passive construction as explained by AlanCarmack in the comment.

Comment: Do I need to use "to be" (instead of is/am/are) to express a passive sentence in simple present tense?

Comment: @NguyenBinh - No, the passive simple present uses "is", as in "The door is watched by a guard."

Comment: The point is that there is only one finite verb per clause (and it always comes first).  Only that verb carries the tense and subject agreement.  Any subsequent verbs are infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You can say either:

> I need|want this car fixed.
>
> I need|want this car to be fixed.

car fixed, house painted, sidewalk swept, grass mowed, etc

I want|need something  (to be) {past-participle}.